# (SSG-WSG) How do i connect to the API Gateway using the certificate method?

Tags: c#, api

I'm using the certificate authorization method, below is my code and it keeps returning me "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel". I'm not sure what is the correct procedure to authorize my certificate to the API Gateway.

```
        public static Courses RetrieveCourses()
        {
            var model = new Courses();

            //url settings
            var hostname = "https://api.ssg-wsg.sg";
            var URL = hostname + "/skillsFramework/sectors";

            //Certificates
            var folderpath = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
            X509Certificate Cert1 = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile(folderpath + "cert.pem");

            //private key
            var bytesToDecrypt = RsaProviderFromPrivateKeyInPemFile(folderpath + "key.pem"); //Convert.FromBase64String(privateKeyPem.ToString());

            X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(Cert1);
            certificate.PrivateKey = bytesToDecrypt;

            var output = new JObject();
            ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            

            
            try
            {
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
                request.Method = "GET";
                request.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);
                request.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate);
               

                using (HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
                {
                    if (webResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            using (Stream webStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream() ?? Stream.Null)
                            using (StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(webStream))
                            {

                                string response = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
                                output = JObject.Parse(response);
                            }
                        }

                        catch (WebException ex)
                        {
                            WebResponse errorResponse = ex.Response;
                            using (Stream responseStream = errorResponse.GetResponseStream())
                            {
                                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8"));
                                String errorText = reader.ReadToEnd();
                                Log.Write("SFEC Courses API " + ex.Response + " " + ex.Message + " -- Inner exception: " + ex.InnerException + " -- Stack: " + ex.StackTrace);

                            }
                            throw;

                        }
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        request.Abort();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Write("API CALL: " + ex.Message + " -- Inner exception: " + ex.InnerException + " -- Stack: " + ex.StackTrace);
            }

            return model;
        }

        public static RSACryptoServiceProvider RsaProviderFromPrivateKeyInPemFile(string privateKeyPath)
        {
            using (TextReader privateKeyTextReader = new StringReader(File.ReadAllText(privateKeyPath)))
            {
                PemReader pr = new PemReader(privateKeyTextReader);
                AsymmetricKeyParameter keyPair = (AsymmetricKeyParameter)pr.ReadObject();
                RSAParameters rsaParams = DotNetUtilities.ToRSAParameters((RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters)keyPair);

                RSACryptoServiceProvider csp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
                csp.ImportParameters(rsaParams);
                return csp;
            }
        }

        public static bool ValidateServerCertificate( object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Validating certificate {0}", certificate.Issuer);
            if (sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None)
                return true;

            Log.Write("Certificate error: {0}", sslPolicyErrors.ToString());

            // Do not allow this client to communicate with unauthenticated servers.
            return false;
        }
```

Can share what is the correct way to authenticate via the certificate method? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are not using the supported TLS version and SSL cipher for the API call. You can refer to the FAQ - Create App section (https://developer.ssg-wsg.sg/webapp/faq) for more information on the supported SSL/TLS and the GitHub sample code on connecting to the API Gateway using the certificate method in https://github.com/ssg-wsg/community/tree/master/guides/certificate